# Are C++ arrays copy constructible?

Tags: c++

Is this code valid in C++?

```
class MyClass    
{
    public:
    Class2 array [100];
    Myclass (const Myclass& other) : array (other.array) {}
};
```

If it isn't, what's the best way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not this is valid, if all your copy constructor does is to copy the array, then I would rather avoid writing it and let the compiler generate one implicitly.

Also, I would recommend following [chris's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515694/are-c-arrays-copy-constructible/17515724#comment25467431_17515694) in C++11 and use `std::array` rather than C-style arrays:

```
#include <array>

class MyClass
{
public: // In case you really want this to be public
    std::array<Class2, 100> arr;
};
```

By the way, this would also allow you to initialize you array in the copy constructor's initializer list (but again, do this only if needed):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { }
    MyClass (const MyClass& other) : arr(other.arr) {}
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

private:
    std::array<Class2, 100> arr;
};
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=45fd833114e09e10d2550fe790eece39-a73d80d9462cfb550c0755cfd96ceec5).

Comment: @jrok: Why not? (apart from missing semicolons etc.)

Comment: Last time I tried that I couldn't initialize an array like this.

Comment: @jrok: Hm, perhaps GCC implements a non-conforming extension then (I tried it and it compiles)

Comment: [Clang doesn't.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2582fb9ce8fe81fb40c3f84c76ff527b-78af1489b09c6514c070d1f877502981).

Comment: @icepack: GCC 4.8.1 [accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8a0add1f51b7fbae060fed7d58a3781d-79e5e73fba6f6ecc33fd7fa082b8effd).

Comment: n3337 8.5/16 5th bullet says **"— Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.".** Unless I misread something in first four bullets, OP snippet is ill-formed.

Comment: @jrok: Right. Things would be different if braces were used (8.5.4/3), which is probably what confused me since the beginning, together with the fact that GCC 4.8.1 accepts the OP's code

Comment: @jrok: Actually, thinking about it, things would not be different. I would be trying to initialize an array aggregate from an array, which is wrong. Forgive the noise.

Answer (score 11):

In C++ arrays are not explicitly copyable (not copy-constructible, not assignable). Your code will not compile.

Yet in C++ arrays become indirectly copyable when wrapped into a class. This means that if you remove your constructor definition, then the implicit copy constructor generated by the compiler for your class `MyClass` will actually successfully copy the array by some "magical" means that are not available to you directly.

But if for some reason you have to define the copy constructor explicitly, then your options are restricted to leaving the array default-initialized and then explicitly copying the data in the body of the constructor through `std::copy` or something similar. Or you can simply re-wrap your array, which is actually what the already suggested `std::array` can do for you.

Comment: Well, I need to define a copy constructor explicitly. Besides the array, the class involves other member data that require a deep copy. Thanks :)