# why std::pair<int[N], int[N]> is not allowed in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, std-pair

Why the C++ code below can't be compiled?

```
#include <utility>

int main() {
    int x[6];
    int y[6];
    std::pair<int[6], int[6]> a(x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

For example MSVC gives the following error:

> error C2661: 'std::pair<int [6],int [6]>::pair': no overloaded function takes 2 argument

Thanks for the comments that using C++ alternatives to construct arrays, but I also want to know the reason that the code can't be compiled.

Comment: Use `std::array<int,6>` instead of c arrays: [https://ideone.com/eEKplR](https://ideone.com/eEKplR)

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal: `int[6]` certainly is a type.

Comment: C style arrays will either not work or not behave as you expect in many contexts.  Prefer C++ alternatives.

Comment: an array decays into a pointer when passed into a function, which results in `int*`. Which means `int* != int[6]`. You should use a `std::array<int,6>` or wrap it into a struct yourself.

Comment: Arrays are not copyable in C++ (i.e. if `a` and `b` are arrays you cannot write `a = b;`). This makes using them in templates (and many other places) problematic.

Comment: Because of [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). In particular, `a` and `b` decay to pointers to `int` in your example. Also built in array assignment `array1 = array2;` is not allowed. [Arrays cannot appear on the left hand side of assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987133/array-type-is-not-assignable)

Comment: Just to be clear, the primary problem here isn't that arrays decay to pointers. It's that  arrays aren't copy-assignable.

Comment: [Are C++ arrays copy constructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515694/are-c-arrays-copy-constructible) and [Assign array to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962441/assign-array-to-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `int[]` as a type of element in a `std::pair` is actually allowed.
For example you could use:

```
std::pair<int[6], int[6]> a;
a.first[0] = 1;
```

What's not valid is the initialization of the pair with `(x,y)`. C arrays are not copy assignable: you cannot assign some array `a2` to another `a1` by the trivial assignment `a1 = a2;`. And C arrays decay into pointers when passed to a funtion/method.

However, the prefered way to do it in C++ is to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

using IntArr6 = std::array<int, 6>;
IntArr6 x{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
IntArr6 y{ 11,22,33,44,55,66 };
std::pair<IntArr6, IntArr6> aa{ x,y };
```

Note the usage of `using` (providing a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)) to make the code more readable.